# mysqli ignoring the first row in a table

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is the code I'm using to pull the data from the table:

```
require_once 'connect.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `db-news`";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    printf ($row['pagename'].' - To edit this page <a href="editnews.php?id='.$row['id'].'">click here</a><br>');
}
```

**Always the first row is ignored.** I'm not calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc` twice as with some other examples on SO. I've tried changing `echo` to `printf` in the while loop and still the first row is ignored in the DB.

I'm at a loss as to what I should try next?

Comment: Remove this line `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

mysqli not ignoring it but actually you are fetching first row before while loop

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); //remove this line
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the first row of the following excerpt:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

The `mysqli_fetch_assoc` already gets the first row (and thus in the while loop you are already 1 step further).
You should either put that line instead of the `$reslut->fetch_assoc` part into the while statement or delete it. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc()` is the same as `$result->fetch_assoc()` and whenever you call this function it will advance an internal pointer to the next row. You are calling this function once just before the loop which means that you are reading the first row and ignoring the result. Remove that line.

If you need to fetch the first line and then still loop through the whole result use `foreach` instead of `while`. For example:

```
require_once 'connect.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `db-news`";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
foreach($result as $row) {
    printf($row['pagename'].' - To edit this page <a href="editnews.php?id='.$row['id'].'">click here</a><br>');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `do while` instead of `while` as it will not skip the first step.