# Missing row from mysqli $query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem with MySqli not outputting the result of my query.

```
$cxn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pw,$dbname) or die("Error connecting to server");

if(!$cxn=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pw,$dbname)){

        $message=mysqli_error($cxn);
        echo $message;
        die();

}

$query= "SELECT * from merchantinfo WHERE industry='Retail'";
$result=mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die("Could not execute the query");
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
extract($row);
echo "$INDUSTRY: $NAME<br/>";
}
```

And this is the table i'm currently using.(merchantinfo)

```
MerchantID    INDUSTRY    NAME              DESCRIPTION
1             Dining      Burger King       Whopper,Whoppers galore!
2             Retail      ZARA              A large clothing retailer
3             Aviation    Virgin Airlines   Lolwut
```

i am currently getting a totally blank page as my result after my query, though i cant seem to figure out the problem. i've tried changing the 'industry' in $query and the while loop to all caps to match the capitalisation in the table, i've also tried using them all in small caps. Yet i am still getting a blank page as a output.

I've also tried changing the $query to

```
$query="SELECT * FROM merchantinfo";
```

which produces the result :

```
Retail:ZARA
Aviation:Virgin Airlines
```

i would appreciate it if someone could point out the mistake in the code or point me in the right direction

Thanks!

Comment: For some reason this is a most popular question for the tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli ignoring the first row in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358552/mysqli-ignoring-the-first-row-in-a-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

It is fetching your first row and is unnecessary (it is essentially discarding it).

Also, unless your column names are uppercase this won't work:

```
extract($row);
echo "$INDUSTRY: $NAME<br/>";
```

It would need to be the same case as your actual column names.

Comment: @ John Conde I've got it. Just a quick question as to why $row_mysqli_fetch_array($result) isn't needed? Isn't the purpose of the $row just to store the temporary location of the query's result?If so, why would it be unnecessary, and discarding my first row?

Comment: It actually fetches the row for you which is what you're doing in your while loop below. It's very similar to mysql_fetch_assoc() but just returns the data differently.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc returns keys as strings while array returns them as numbers AND keys. However, if i should change the fetch_array above the while loop to fetch_assoc instead, the first row of results would disappear. I'm assuming that this is because the first row has already been fetched by the mysql_fetch_assoc above the while loop, though i dont get why the while loop would be unable to access it since both "fetch" are fetch_assoc?

Comment: Once you fetch a row the cursor moves to the next record. So by calling mysql_fetch_* you essentially move pas the first record. Then when you do your loop you start at the second record. It doesn't reset the cursor.